# Finding exacts matches while ignoring custom tags

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, lucene.net.linq

I'm working with an index where there's a mix of documents and some might contain custom tags like:

> - "Some long sentence `<custom-tag attr="value" />` which ends here"
> - "Some long sentence `<custom-tag attr="value" />` which ends `<custom-tag-2 attr="value2" />` here"
> - "Another long sentence `<another-custom-tag attr="value" />` which ends `<another-custom-tag attr=value />` here"

I'm supposed to find exact matches completely agnostic to tag's names and attributes.
Building such an hypothetical query, the first thing which comes to my mind are regular expressions, for example:

> - "Some long sentence `regex(<[^>]*>?` which ends here"

would return the first document, and

> - "Some long sentence `regex(<[^>]*>?` which ends `regex(<[^>]*>?` here"

would return the second document.

Is this something I could achieve with **Lucene 3.x** ? I'm even considering migrating to **Lucene 4.8 Beta** if it justifies.

As anyone dealt with something similar? Are there pitfalls I should consider?

I guess the easiest way would to store the same text but stripped away from tags on a second field and perform the search on that one instead.
I'd appreciate any input or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option (in any version) is to create a TokenFilter which would recognise the tag/regex and omit them from the token stream.

btw: I've found it "good" to never store the fields (possibly excepting the "identifier" field. Then serializing the object into a binary field. This separates the "index" from the "data". There is some benefit in search speed and IO requirements

Comment: awesome feedback as usual. Do you have any references discussing the performance gains in serializing the object into a binary field?

Comment: Thanks :)
The evidence is mostly empirical experience and will depend on the number of fields that are stored. The main part is in how you retrieve the fields. `doc.Get("name")` just iterates over the fields so it's O(n/2). Also when getting the data it needs to skip to that part of the blob.
So lots of iterating and skipping around.
Serializing into a single field and putting it first made a difference. For large objects it reduced the index size significantly. I used compressed json but others may give perf/size YMMV
If you're just storing an id to fetch from a DB... none of this matters